# Fatal Python error: PyEval_AcquireThread

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I just put up a django application online and i'm getting this error in my error log

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_AcquireThread: NULL new thread state
```

I have seen a few similar questions online, but they do not explain this error.

Comment: You're getting a C error, not a Python error, so the error is in one of your C libraries. Can you provide some more information, like: Are you in some way extending/embedding Python? What Python extensions are you using? On what environment it the application deployed?

Comment: i do not under stand what that means (extending/embedding Python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tends to indicate that your mod_wsgi is compiled for a different Python version and/or a different Python installation than the Python virtual environment or Python installation it is trying to use at runtime.

In other words, you are mixing compiled shared library and extension modules from different Python installations. This can cause all sorts of problems.

Go through the checks in:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation

to understand how your mod_wsgi has been built and verify it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I have the same error, however I'm using the Debian's standard Python version + the official Debian package `libapache2-mod-wsgi`, so I don't think it's a Python version mismatch... This bug seems hard to debug indeed.

Answer (score 7):

The problem can appear if apache `mod_wsgi` and `mod_python` are both enabled.
Try

```
sudo a2dismod python
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This is not really a good solution because in some cases, we would like to keep the good and simple `mod_python` too on the same VirtualHost.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was permissions for the directories where Django or Flask project are. They were created from root, so I changed them to www-data in my case.